# Error with scope in javascript, related to function

Tags: javascript, function

The code below serves theoretically to compare all Google Maps API bookmarks that I've integrated into the website, where custom bookmarks have a radius of 750 meters, and I'm trying to calculate the radius and know if they overlap, and for that I've been searching the internet and incremented the basic APIv3 code plus the javascript function code for the calculation to check if the markers' rays meet.

Until the map view part, the markers in the addresses registered in the database table (110 total) plus the address reservation addresses (5 total) were displayed, however at the end of the setMarkers() function; I incremented a **for in** by calling another function, the **hasIntersections(); function**, and then the "error" happens.

As I am beginner in javascript I do not know how to fix, in the console the error displayed is, which is in the **hasIntersections() function;**

> "Uncaught TypeError: circle0.getCenter is not a function"

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
</script>

<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var image = 'https://www.keepidea.com.br/painel/assets/images/mark-teste.png';

var locations2 = [['RESERVA: ', -23.9446791, -46.3264323, 'Av. Senador Feijó, 421 - Vila Nova, Santos - SP, 11013-162, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Assunção, 414 - Sion, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30320-040, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Padre Feijó, 373 - Vila Tiberio, Ribeirão Preto - SP, 14050-360, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', -23.0654964, -47.2263359, 'R. Vitoriano Salut, 72 - Chácara Belvedere, Indaiatuba - SP, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', -20.8873894, -47.5997438, 'Rua Ana Luiza, 197 - Bairro Castelo, Batatais - SP, 14300-000, Brasil']];

var locations = [['Vila Osasco', -23.544559, -46.781034, 'Avenida Santo Antônio, 2761, Vila Osasco,  - SP, 06083-215, Brasil'],['Rebouças', -22.8904057, -43.5603237, 'Avenida Rebouças, 3657, Centro,  - SP, 13170-023, Brasil'],['Nutrition Bauru', -22.3370765, -49.0891827, 'Avenida Castelo Branco, 7-15, Vila Independência,  - SP, 17052-000, Brasil'],['Pitangueiras', -23.2022764, -46.8836439, 'Rua Pitangueiras, 790, Jardim Pitangueiras,  - SP, 13206-716, Brasil'],['Vale do Sol', -20.4229151, -49.9592271, 'Avenida pansani, 3092, Vale do sol,  - SP, 15500-302, Brasil'],['Cidade Nova Montes Claros-Mg', -16.739527, -43.8653989, 'Avenida Dona Gregória, 101, Cidade Nova,  - MG, 39400-464, Brasil'],['Centro Salto', -23.199741, -47.3008818, 'Avenida Dom Pedro II, 1421, Centro,  - SP, 13320-241, Brasil'],['ASSIS', -22.6575047, -50.397561, 'Rua Antônio da Silva Cunha Bueno, 425, Jardim Paulista,  - SP, 19815-080, Brasil'],['Paulinia', -22.743178, -47.1744984, 'Avenida João Aranha, 946, Alto de Pinheiros,  - SP, 13145-256, Brasil'],['SBC Centro', -23.7132318, -46.5532384, 'Rua Joaquim Nabuco, 56, Centro,  - SP, 09720-375, Brasil'],['Chácara', -23.6290144, -46.7025941, 'Rua da paz, 1498, Chácara Santo Antônio,  - SP, 04713-000, Brasil'],['Nova Europa', -22.9424831, -47.0573369, 'Avenida Baden Powell, 1831, Nova Europa,  - SP, 13040-093, Brasil'],['Morada do Sol', -23.1269188, -47.244239, 'Rua João Martini, 475, Jardim Morada do Sol,  - SP, 13348-350, Brasil'],['Campo grande RJ', -22.890374, -43.560187, 'Rua do petróleo, 14, Campo Gande,  - RJ, 23087-125, Brasil'],['Tremembé', -23.4587589, -46.6149244, 'Avenida Nova Cantareira, 4794, Tucuruvi,  - SP, 02340-002, Brasil'],['Vila das Belezas', -23.6491279, -46.7543918, 'Estrada de Itapecerica, 2219, Vila das Belezas,  - SP, 05835-005, Brasil'],['CCentro', -23.0854053, -47.2105986, 'Rua Humaitá, 1099, Centro,  - SP, 13339-140, Brasil'],['ITAPECERICA', -23.698334, -46.8527042, 'Rua Ari Batalha, 393, Parque Paraiso,  - SP, 06850-335, Brasil'],['lapa', -23.5250071, -46.6872423, 'Rua Clélia, 911, Lapa,  - SP, 05042-000, Brasil'],['Interação Flamboyant', -17.7718674, -48.6186493, 'Rua B-02, S/N, Estância Itanhanga,  - GO, 75690-000, Brasil'],['Tatuapé', -23.552282, -46.5566401, 'Rua Francisco Marengo, 1717, Tatuapé,  - SP, 03313-001, Brasil'],['Flamboyant', -22.8762222, -47.0358206, 'Rua Comendador Doutor Antônio Pompeo Camargo, 104, Jardim Boa Esperança,  - SP, 13091-502, Brasil'],['N.Sr de Fatima', -22.8975439, -47.1685964, 'Armelinda Espúrio da Silva, 565, Jardim Nossa Senhora de Fátima,  - SP, 13084-450, Brasil'],['Agapeama', -23.2053398, -46.8651296, 'Rua da Varzea Paulista, 487, Vila Agricola,  - SP, 13202-700, Brasil'],['Buriti', -23.2230818, -46.8760877, 'Rua Dom Pedro I, 462, Jardim Buriti,  - SP, 13225-790, Brasil'],['BOA VISTA', -14.8793362, -40.832031, 'Avenida Gilenilda Alves, 1345, Boa Vista,  - BA, 45027-560, Brasil'],['FABRICA DE RESULTADOS', -23.6008617, -46.8988726, 'Rua Pinhal, 83, Jardim Sabia,  - SP, 06716-575, Brasil'],['Valentina Cross Life',-16.7287284, -43.8835938, 'Rua Espírito Santo Esplanada, 395, Esplanada,  - MG, 39401-452, Brasil'],['PEDRO PINHO', -23.5402247, -46.8010548, 'Avenida General Pedro Pinho, 1052, Pestana,  - SP, 06122-160, Brasil']];

function initMap()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-84.568808, -100.418683);
    var options = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        zoom: 4
    });
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
    setMarkers(map,locations);
    setMarkers(map,locations2);
}

Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
    return this * (Math.PI / 180.0);
};

function distance(lat0, long0, lat1, long1)
{
    var rlat0 = lat0.toRadians();
    var rlong0 = long0.toRadians();
    var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
    var rlong1 = long1.toRadians();
    var deltaLat = (rlat1-rlat0);
    var deltaLong = (rlong1-rlong0);
    var a = Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) + Math.pow( Math.sin(deltaLong / 2), 2) * Math.cos(rlat0) * Math.cos(rlat1);  
    return (2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))) * 6378137;
}

function hasIntersections(circle0,circle1)
{
    var center0 = circle0.getCenter();
    var center1 = circle1.getCenter();
    var maxDist = circle0.getRadius()+circle1.getRadius();
    var actualDist = distance(center0.lat(),center0.lng(),center1.lat(),center1.lng());
    return maxDist>=actualDist;
}

circles = [];
circles2 = [];
circle = null;
circle2 = null;

function setMarkers(map,locations)
{

    var marker = null;
    var i = null;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        var loan = locations[i][0]
        var lat = locations[i][1]
        var long = locations[i][2]
        var add =  locations[i][3]
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset,
            icon: image
        });

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            radius: 750,
            strokeColor: "#818c99",
            fillColor: "#ffffff",
            fillOpacity: 0.50
        });

        circles.push(cityCircle);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function()
            {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow));

    }

    var marker = null;
    var i = null;

    for (i = 0; i < locations2.length; i++)
    {
        var loan = locations2[i][0]
        var lat = locations2[i][1]
        var long = locations2[i][2]
        var add =  locations2[i][3]
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset,
            icon: image
        });

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            radius: 750,
            strokeColor: "#229A1F",
            fillColor: "#49DA45",
            fillOpacity: 0.50
        });

        circles2.push(cityCircle);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow));
    }

    for ( var circle1 in circles )
    {
        for ( var circle2 in circles2 )
        {
            console.log(hasIntersections(circle1, circle2)); 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I did a test on the console, with console.log (circles), and the result was a total of 5 results like:

> _.qg {gm_accessors_: {…}, map: gg, gm_bindings_: {…}, zoom: 4, center: _.L, …} A :
>   *.Rw {Ck: 0, **e3***: {…}, b: "planetRadius", f: false, getPlanetRadius: ƒ, …} center :
>   _.L {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ} closure_uid_660309532 : 1199 draggable_changed : ƒ c() editable_changed : ƒ e() f : gg {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Cf,
>   gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 4, center: _.L, …} fillColor : "#49DA45"
>   fillOpacity :
>   0.5 gm_accessors_ : {map: null, zoom: null, center: null, radius: null, strokeColor: null, …} gm_bindings_ : {map: {…}, zoom: {…},
>   center: {…}, radius: {…}, strokeColor: {…}, …} hh : hW {Ck: 0, __e3_:
>   {…}, b: _.sg, gm_bindings_: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, …} ja : (9) [Mc,
>   Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc] map : gg {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Cf,
>   gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 4, center: _.L, …} radius : 750 strokeColor
>   : "#229A1F" vh : (3) [Mc, Mc, Mc] visible : true zoom : 4
>   __e3_ : {toolbar: {…}, mouseover: {…}, click: {…}, mouseout: {…}}
>   __proto : Object

And for console.log (circles2) the result in the total of 110, for circles and circles2 the values beat, because for var location [] has 109 and var location [] has 5, total of 115, which has registered in the database data.

Comment: change `for...in` to `for...of`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hey, the max, it worked perfectly, immense gratitude!

Comment: The explanation being that for in loops over all the properties inside the array, including those that aren't circles. So when the for in loop would try to compare a non-circle with a circle, you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `console.log(circle0, circle1)` inside `hasIntersections()`, you will probably get `0, 1, 2, ...` because that is what you get when you use `for (a in array)`.

To fix it, call it like this:

```
for ( var circle1 in circles )
    {
        for ( var circle2 in circles2 )
        {
            console.log(hasIntersections(circles[circle1], circles2[circle2])); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: It did not work, thank you and sorry!

Comment: What did not work?

Comment: Returns another error, can not recognize getCenter (); The answer above @Patrick solved the problem. Gratitude.